# Can I return json data from my MVC program to my view using a class?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following code:

```
return Json(new {
    entity = vm.Entity,
    errors = e.Message,
    field = vm.Field
});
```

If I typed the following it would still compile okay but then fail when the view tried to read the data.

```
return Json(new {
    wrongspellingofentity = vm.Entity,
    errors = e.Message,
    field = vm.Field
});
```

Is there any way I can use some kind of class to return my data and then if so how would I handle reading this on the client. Is there such a thing as a javascript class that I could use to accept the data there?

Comment: post the JSON you are receiving in the client

Answer (score 0):

Using an Anonymouse Type is the same as using a class, since the compiler creates the anonymous type as a class.

Simply specifying a class to convert to JSON will work as it does now with the result being exactly as it is.

Consider:

```
return Json(new MyType{
     entity = vm.Entity,
     errors = e.Message
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that changing a property on the server-side is not picked up by the client side, using a C# class won't really help.  JavaScript doesn't natively support classes and has no reason to complain as long as you pass valid JSON.

You could generate JavaScript pseudo-classes off C# assemblies and, when you load JSON data, have the resulting JavaScript object turned into one of those classes with a mechanism to invalidate missing or incorrect properties.  It is technically possible but, not knowing your intent, I don't know if I'd recommend that over being disciplined when generating and interpreting JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a custom viewmodel (it is just a POCO class) to your client.

Assuming you have a class like this

```
public class CustomerInfo
{
  public string Name { set;get;}
  public int Age { set;get;}
}
```

You  can return it from your Action method like this

```
public Actionresult GetCustomerInf()
{
 var cm=new CustomerInfo();
 cm.Name="Some Name";
 cm.Age=23;
 return Json(cm,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

This is going to return a `JSON` like this

```
{  "Name":"Some Name", "Age":"23" }
```

To access this from client side javascript, you may use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method.

```
$.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCustomerInfo","YourController")",function(data){
  //now you can parse through the JSON result we received back
  alert(data.Name);
  alert(data.Age);
});
```

If you are returning a complex type from your action method, you can get the JSON structure and change the code where you parse the result.

[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) is a useful site which helps you to validate the structure while working with `JSON`.